# Play sound from the file browser window before selecting the file?

Tags: animation

How can I listen to the sound, while on the file browser window, before selecting the file?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit hard to tell from your question what you need help with. Could you maybe provide a bit more detail about what you're trying to do, and where you're stuck?

Comment: There is not such feature in blender. @susu thanks for edit

Comment: @vklidu that is the answer indeed.

Comment: When selecting a sound or sound effect, I want to hear it before selecting it to put it into the Sequencer panel.